# Can I attach my Canadian credit profile to my American credit profile?

Tags: united-states, canada, credit, social-security

I'm a dual citizen of the United States and Canada. I have a social insurance number (Canada) and social security number (US). I have a great credit profile attached to the SIN, but no credit profile attached to the SSN.

This sometimes causes problems when I'm living in the US. Since my SIN has no credit history attached, I'm sometimes unable to rent things if the company doesn't have an alternative process for foreigners; that process often just being a large deposit.

Is there any way for me to copy my credit history in Canada over to the US, or is the only solution to take out a US credit card and start building a separate credit profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved from the UK to Canada, and I had to start afresh with no credit rating. However that isn't really as bad as you might think. Rental places mostly just asked for "a major credit card" and didn't care where it was issued. Car companies certainly do this all the time. I opened a bank account, which just needed lots of ID, and persuaded the bank to give me a low-limit Canadian credit card by showing them a letter from my employer. Then it's just a case of using the credit card a bit to build up a history.